# Trying to use VBA to delete an entire row if one field in null/blank

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

So I am working on a project where I import an excel file into Access, but when I do the importing( the tables in excel have the same tables headings as in Access) I tend to get a bunch of extra rows because in my excel file I have functions behind most of the cells, so that is why, even tho it appears to be empty, Access transfers the rows even tho nothing is actually entered into it.

So my question is, is there a way by using VBA in Access that I can automatically, once the excel file is imported, It could loop through all the rows in a specific table and delete an entire row based on specific criteria. Like if within a row there is an empty field, it will delete the whole entire row. This will save me a lot of time, instead of manually searching through the table for blank fields and deleting the row myself.

I do have knowledge working with VBA but im unsure of how to go about doing this, I was trying to use a DELETE SQL statement, but couldn't figure out how to do it properly since I need it to be In VBA.

Comment: Why is it important to note that your a female?

Comment: You want to delete the blank rows before or after you import?

Comment: after I do the import, since I wont be the only one doing the importing into Access, I want it to do it automatically once is into Access

Comment: Then you should just be able to create a DELETE query in Access, using the conditions you choose, and then calling that through the VBA module.

Comment: The thing is I am unsure of how to create a DELETE query in Access. I don't know of the format to start with. Would the DELETE query just be a regular SQL statement? or do I have to change it since I have to use VBA? where exactly would I put/create the DELETE query?

Comment: See answer below.  Also, I am removing the vb.net tag from your question, since it seems you want a VBA/Access solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a SQL query that pulls back the rows you want to delete.
2. Once the query is finished to your liking, go into SQL View for
       the query, and remove everything before the FROM clause.
3. Instead, type a DELETE there. Save the query.  So it should look like "DELETE FROM blah WHERE blah, blah, blah"

So now you have a query that will delete rows that you want it to.  Now, to get it to run through VBA (note that you can run it manually just by double-clicking it in the Queries pane), just put the following line in where you want it to run.

```
docmd.OpenQuery "yourDeleteQueryName"
```

Note that yourDeleteQueryName should be replaced with your Delete query name.

Comment: Quick Q: Where do you create the SQL query in Access? I know the type of criteria I want, just don't know the where to create it...

Comment: Using the Query Wizard? or Query Design?

Comment: Either will do.  It seems like you have never created a Delete query before, so my suggestion is to create a copy of the db before you try any of this.  Also, maybe Google how to create one.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try that. And I have never used the Delete Query before in Access but I do know how to make a SQL statement, just needed help. Thanks